# WPF ContextMenu with TextBox and Button

Tags: c#, wpf

On `MouseLeftButtonDown` of an `Image`, I want to display a `ContextMenu` that has a `TextBox` where the user enters a path and a `Button` beside it to confirm. Anyone have an idea of how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Is there something you tried until now or you don't have a clue how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Put your TextBox and button in a Popup, and then set Popup.IsOpen = true when you get the MouseLeftButton down on the image.

If you've got some code that you've tried, post it in your question and I will try to help.